# Issue with sleep inside for loop

Tags: python, for-loop, if-statement, sleep

I have a condition in my python code wherein if the condition is met, it should send an email. When the same condition is executed again, it should wait for 60 min before it can send another email. I used an if inside for loop but the issue is that the other rows in the for loop are stuck because of the if loop inside. How do I overcome this?

```html
def send_email(previousindex,index):
    if previousindex!= index or previousindex is None:
        print('email sent')
       
    else:
        print('Wait for 1 hr')
        time.sleep(3600)


while True:
    previousindex = None
   

    for index in df.index:  # row in df.iterrows():

        if df.loc[index, 'Time flag'] == 1:
            print('fail')
            print(previousindex)
            send_email(previousindex,index)
            previousindex = index
            
        else:
            time.sleep(10)
            continue
               



    time.sleep(10)
```

```python
def send_email(previous_index, index):
    if index not in previous_index:
        print('email sent')

    else:
       print(previous_index)

       print('Wait for 1 hr')
       time.sleep(3500)
       previous_index.clear()

       print('email sent')


while True:
    df = pd.read_csv(r'C:/Users/KrishnamurthyKA/Desktop/Project/Test.csv',sep = ',')

    for index in df.index:  # row in df.iterrows():

        if df.loc[index, 'Time flag'] == 1:

            print('pass')
            send_email(previous_index, index)
            previous_index.append(index)
            print(previous_index)

            # if previousindex == index:

            # print('entered if loop')
            # print(previousindex)
            # time.sleep(10)
        else:
            time.sleep(10)
            continue

    print(previous_index)
    time.sleep(10)
```

EDIT 2:

```
min = 2
 while True:
for index in df.index:
    now = datetime.datetime.now()

    if df.loc[index,'Time flag'] == 1 and df.loc[df.index[index], "Last_email_sent"] == None:
        print('pass')
        df.loc[df.index[index], "Last_email_sent"] = now
        print(now)

        #send_email(index)
    elif df.loc[index, 'Time flag'] == 1 and minutes < min:
        print('wait')
        print(minutes)
        print(df.loc[index,'Last_email_sent'])

    elif df.loc[index, 'Time flag'] == 1 and minutes >= min:
        #send_email(index)
        print('sending email after 1 min')
        df.loc[index, "Last_email_sent"] = now

        print(minutes)
        minutes = divmod((now - df.loc[index, "Last_email_sent"]).total_seconds(), 60)[0]
    else:
        print('false')


time.sleep(10)
```

Comment: I don't understand the requirement. If there are multiple flags in the data, should multiple emails be sent? At what times should the email be sent? Do you want to *do the check* continuously, or only once per hour? If you only want to do the check once per hour, is the rest of the program supposed to run during the res of the time? Or just what exactly is the problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: It is not quite clear what you wish to achieve: do you wish your loop to run entirely (across the whole df) BEFORE sending an email with the summary ? Or do you wish to send an email as soon as you detect the first match ? Unless your dataframe is extremely big, it is probably easier to screen the entire df for the condition, and THEN send an email with the summary.

Comment: 2nd set of "if previousindex == index:" is redundant, could have just added send_email(index) with the rest of the code

Comment: Have you considered selecting the data from dataset first and then sending the emails?

Comment: Could have added a record_time for current time email was sent. Next time, if code wants to send an email, check current time again. Then wait_time = curr_time - record_time

Comment: @AnswerSeeker   So when the for loop runs for the first time, it will complete 10 iterations and if any of the rows meet the condition, it will send an email. When the while is evaluated the second time, the for loop runs for the 2nd time but this time, since it has already sent an email for the row that met the condition, it shouldn't run again and wait for 1hr. How do I store the index in a list?

Comment: You can record with time and without time into a list and append it to a dataframe. Performing updates to column of the dataframe as time is updated. Comparing recorded time with current time and check if it exceeded 1hour to allow sending of emails for particular row.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, your logic can be simplified into:

```
while True:
    previous_index = None

    for index in idx:
        # First iteration
        if condition(index) and previous_index is None:

            send_email()
            previous_index = index

        elif condition(index) and previous_index != index:

            send_email()
            previous_index = index

        elif condition(index) and previous_index == index:

            # Wait 1 hour
            time.sleep(3600)

        else:
            time.sleep(10) # Wait a bit
            continue
```

From my interpretation, you get stuck because the process stops during 1 hour every time it enters the `time.sleep(3600)`. Thus during this time, you would like the rest of the loop to keep running on other index.

The problem is that `time.sleep()` pauses the opened python process during the time specified. One way to overcome this is to open an additional process to send the e-mail. The code would look like:

```
def send_email(previous_index, index):

    if previous_index != index or previous_index is None:
        # Send the e-mail
    else:
        # Wait 1 hour
        time.sleep(3600)
        # Send the e-mail

while True:
    previous_index = None

    for index in idx:
        if condition(index):

            Open_process(target = send_email, args = (previous_index, index))
            previous_index = index

        else:
            time.sleep(10) # Wait a bit
            continue
```

Processes have the disadvantage to be a bit slow to open. Threads might be better, however, as you included a sleep of 10 second between each loop, I don't think it matters in this application.

Finally, you can look at the library multiprocessing to manage processes.

**EDIT:**

```
def send_email(index):
    # Function sending the e-mail
    print ("e-mail sent")

# Each index is unique and the loop is executed every 10 s
# Key: index; Value: number of iterations; 360 iterations = 1 hour.
tracking = dict()
# Initialize with None
for index in df.index:
    tracking[index] = None

while True:

    for index in df.index:

        if df.loc[index, 'Time flag'] == 1 and tracking[index] is None:
            send_email(index)
            tracking[index] = 1

        elif df.loc[index, 'Time flag'] == 1 and tracking[index] < 360:
            tracking[index] += 1

        elif df.loc[index, 'Time flag'] == 1 and tracking[index] == 360:
            send_email(index)
            tracking[index] = 1 # Reset since an e-mail is sent.

        else:
            # df.loc[index, 'Time flag'] == 0
            tracking[index] = None

    time.sleep(10)
```

EDIT 2

```
    def send_email(index):
        # Function sending the e-mail
        print ("e-mail sent")

    # Add column to keep tack of last e-mail send timing
    # If the e-mail has never been sent, initialize to Nan, None, or -1
    # No idea what is more convenient, but adapt the first if accordingly
    df.add_column("Last e-mail sent timing")

    while True:

        for index in df.index:

            if df.loc[index, 'Time flag'] == 1 and df[index, "Last e-mail sent timing"] is None:
                send_email(index)
                df[index, "Last e-mail sent timing"] = current.time()

            elif df.loc[index, 'Time flag'] == 1 and current.time - df[index, "Last e-mail sent timing"] < 1 hour:
                # skip
                continue

            elif df.loc[index, 'Time flag'] == 1 and current.time - df[index, "Last e-mail sent timing"] >= 1 hour:
                send_email(index)
                df[index, "Last e-mail sent timing"] = current.time()

        time.sleep(10)
```

EDIT 3:

```
duration_to_wait = 2 # in MINUTES

while True:

    for index in df.index:

        if df.loc[index,'Time flag'] == 1 and df.loc[df.index[index], "Last_email_sent"] == None:
            send_email(index)
            df.loc[df.index[index], "Last_email_sent"] = datetime.datetime.now()

        elif df.loc[index, 'Time flag'] == 1 and datetime.datetime.now() - df.loc[df.index[index], "Last_email_sent"] < datetime.timedelta(minutes=duration_to_wait):
            print('Wait')
            print(datetime.datetime.now() - df.loc[df.index[index], "Last_email_sent"])

        elif df.loc[index, 'Time flag'] == 1 and datetime.datetime.now() - df.loc[df.index[index], "Last_email_sent"] >= datetime.timedelta(minutes=duration_to_wait):
            send_email(index)
            df.loc[index, "Last_email_sent"] = datetime.datetime.now()

        else:
            print('false')

    time.sleep(10)
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/200680/discussion-on-answer-by-mathieu-issue-with-sleep-inside-for-loop).